# Overlapping Calender at Notification Top Bar in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

When we are clicking future calendar date on Calendar Top Bar then calendar is overlapping

[Trying to click on future date in calendar Eg: 5th Oct (blurred date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLbfL.png)

Steps to reproduce :

1. click on Calendar Top Bar
2. it showing current calendar(like September) so need to directly click on future date (Like Oct 5th) without selecting any date in Sep.

[overlapping calendar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LH3s.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: thank you for trying to replicate, i have updated replication steps, can you please help me

Comment: Yes, today I definitely can reproduce an issue, in gnome Boxes on Wayland. The effect is different: when clicking the date for the next month in the bottom, the widget is reduced in height, causing part of the calendar to be "cut off". I can also reproduce it on my main system (running a Gnome session). You found a bug.

Comment: thank you for your detailed information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing bugs with the calendar widget in Gnome Shell. These are known upstream and have been reported in several issues:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5469

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5411

Since the problems are known, there is little more we can do as ordinary users than wait until this get fixed in an update.